# line detection, when the gray value of contour and background is very similar

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I am working on a project. In this project I need to use a robotic gripper to gripp a flange. This flange will be detected and located in a monocamera. This flange contour comes from a FOUP handling flange. What I need to do is to detect the most outer edge. Because that edge is determined by a CAD model. The internal edge is not useful.(image 0)

I have already tried to detect the edge by using bilateral filter and Canny detector. But this works not very well. Because the internal edge is more clear than the outer edge. The result is, there are many edges at the contour. 
And that contour is also not continuous.

Image below is the oringinal image.

[image: Original image]

Those are the lines, which I need to detect.

[image: lines to be detected]

This is the result from canny detector.

[image: results from canny]

This is the original image for this flange.
[image]

Below is the edge image.
[image]

This edge detection I just use the canny detector in opencv.

Comment: Why don’t you detect the inner edge, then expand that with the known distance to the outer edge?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I also thought about that. But the distance between inner and outer edge ist not known. There is also anather typ of flange. The inner edge is not very reliable. Is it possible, that I use the edge direction to find the outer edge? Have you ever seen this approch before?                                                                    Thank you

Comment: I think it would be good if you added the code that produced the edge detection. Not five pages of code but just the minimum code you wrote to do the edge detection. It will probably be just a few lines (see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ).This will increase your chances of getting a useful answer. It would also help your question if you tagged it with the language you use.

Comment: Your original image is not the same as the one with the edge detection. The original image has the branding at the top which the others don't. Would you be able to replace the `original image` with the cropped version you used to create the edge detection?

Comment: I have post the original image. This time is better to see the difference. The edge detector I have choosed Canny detector in OpenCV Python. On this flange there is also much texture, I have used bilateral filter to filter the noise, which is better to retain the edge information than gaussian filter.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of edge detection. Detection of faint edges is an unsolved problem.